# Is it possible to add rings using other polygons?

Tags: qgis

I would like to "Add Rings" but using other polygons. Example:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ue1k3b646ivqedo/holes.JPG

I would like to delete the two selected polygons and create holes under them in the big polygon where they are.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can save the "hole" polygons and the "base" polygons in two different, temporary shapefiles and then you use the **symmetrical difference** tool. You find it in *vector>geoprocessing tools* (if you are using a very old qgis version it is in the fTools plug-in). This create the shapefile that you are looking for.
If you have already 2 shapefiles (bases and "hole"), just run the tool ;).

Comment: For temporary shapefiles, use Memory Layer Plugin

Comment: @Aitor good! (it will also be nice if you mark my answer as useful ;) )

Comment: @seba i cant since i dont reach 15 of reputation when i reach ill do it. thanks again for your help